# Vue js: sort words by property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have like this code in my project:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  Words sorted by priority: <br/>
  <pre>
    <words-list></words-list>
  </pre>
</div>

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        words: ['Circle', 'Blue', 'Apple'],
    }
})

Vue.component('words-list', {
    template: `
        <ul>
            <li v-for="word in sortWordsByPriority(words)" 
                v-show="isActive(word)"
            >{{ word }}</li>
        </ul>
    `,
    props: {
        wordsPriority: {
            Apple: 20,
            Blue: 10,
            Circle: 0,
        },
        wordsActive: [
            'Apple',
            'Blue',
        ],
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            words: this.$store.state.words
        }
    },
    methods: {
        isActive(word) {
            return wordsActive.includes(word);
        },

        sortWordsByPriority(words) {
            this.words.sort((a, b) => this.wordsPriority[b] - this.wordsPriority[a]);
        },
    },
});

new Vue({
    store,
    el: "#app",
})
```

But when I run my code get error with message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Circle' of undefined
```

Where I have an error in my code?

Comment: one issue I see (not the cause of the problem) `sortWordsByPriority` doesn't return anything ... so `word in sortWordsByPriority(words)` === `word in undefined`

Comment: anyway, which line of code throws that error

Comment: It looks it's an issue with `this` and also `return` `sortWordsByPriority(words) {
            return this.words.sort((a, b) => wordsPriority[b] - wordsPriority[a]);
        }`

Comment: you'll want `return this.words.slice().sort ...` to avoid an infinite loop, since `this.words.sort` mutates `this.words`

Comment: Your `sortWordsByPriority` does not return any thing. But you are calling it in a loop as if it returned an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to have the props defined correctly, if you want to pass a default value, you need to specify the value as `default`. This seems to be

```js
props: {
  wordsPriority: {
    default: {
      Apple: 20,
      Blue: 10,
      Circle: 0,
    },
  },
  wordsActive: {
    default: [
      'Apple',
      'Blue',
    ]
  },
},
```

Also, as mentioned in comments, part of the issue is because of your method doesn't return anything. This can be easily remedied by adding a return.

```js
sortWordsByPriority(words) {
  return this.words.sort((a, b) => this.wordsPriority[b] - this.wordsPriority[a]);
},
```

But you should consider making that a computed value. Because the value of `words` is accessible through vuex, there's no need to define it as a `data`

```js
computed:{
  sortWordsByPriority() {
    return [...this.$store.state.words].sort((a, b) => this.wordsPriority[b] - this.wordsPriority[a]);
  },
}
```

if you use a `computed`, you can use in template as

```html
<li v-for="word in sortWordsByPriority" v-show="isActive(word)">{{ word }}</li>
```